# How to call many times "animate" from class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have method in class:

```
function myClass(){

    this.showTab = function(){

        $('#tab-image').stop().animate(
            { left: 500 + 'px' },
            500 , function(){
                alert('end');
            }
        );

    }

}
```

and I call this method twice:

```
var obj = new myClass();
obj.showTab();
$('#tab-image').css({ left: -500 + 'px' });
obj.showTab();
```

This code works but in second time show without animate. How to do it well?

Comment: The second animation is probably overlapping with the first one. You should call it the second time within the callback function of the first one.

Comment: did you mean "var obj= new myClass()"?  Since myClass() returns nothing, "obj" should be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The **animate function runs in an *asynchronous mode***. That means that second animate doesn't wait to the first one to finish, so, both are executed in parallel.
That's why the animate has a second parameter: to set a callback function that will be executed after the animate finishes.

This should work:

```
function myClass() {

    this.showTab = function(callback) {

        $('#tab-image').stop().animate({
            left: 500 + 'px'
        }, 500, callback);

    }

}

var obj = new myClass();
obj.showTab(function() {
    $('#tab-image').css({
        'left': -500 + 'px'
    });
    obj.showTab();
});​
```

Or if you need to do something else before the callback function:

```
function myClass() {

    this.showTab = function(callback) {

        $('#tab-image').stop().animate({
            left: 500 + 'px'
        }, 500, function() {
            //Insert your code here
            if(typeof callback === "function") callback();
        });

    }

}
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by a quick build-up of animation effects.

What you should do to prevent this is passing two parameters to stop() method;

```
  stop(true, true)
```

This will cause the queue of effects to be clear queue and that it jump to the end.